# Integrate $x^{-d/2}(1-x)^{(d-3)/2}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to find the result of $$\int x^{-d/2}(1-x)^{(d-3)/2}dx$$ where $0<x<1$ and $d\ge2$ is an integer.

Mathematica gives the following:

```
Clear[d];
Integrate[x^(-d/2) (1 - x)^((d - 3)/2), x, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]
```

```
-((2 x^(1 - d/2)Hypergeometric2F1[(3 - d)/2, 1 - d/2, 2 - d/2, x])/(-2 + d))
```

This seems to be fine except for even values of $d\ge4$ because in this case the hypergeometric series is not defined. I've also tried the following:

```
Clear[d];
d = 2 k;
$Assumptions = k > 0 && k \[Element] Integers;
Integrate[x^(-d/2) (1 - x)^((d - 3)/2), x, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]
```

but Mathematica still gives the same expression:

```
(x^(1 - k) Hypergeometric2F1[1 - k, 3/2 - k, 2 - k, x])/(1 - k)
```

If I try to evaluate this expression for any integer value of $k\ge1$ it gives

```
ComplexInfinity
```

as expected.

However, the integral clearly exists as if I tell Mathematica to integrate $\int x^{-d/2}(1-x)^{(d-3)/2}dx$ for a specific value of $d$ it always gives an answer; for example, for $d=4$:

```
d = 4;
Integrate[x^(-d/2) (1 - x)^((d - 3)/2), x, Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]
```

```
-(Sqrt[1 - x]/x) + ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - x]]
```

I need an expression for general $d$, however. Any idea how I can get Mathematica to do this integral in general?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I am slightly confused. You are integrating over $x$, yet you are putting the $x$ range to assumptions. Clearly you want a _definite_ integral, $\int_0^1 x^{-d/2}(1-x)^{(d-3)/2}\, \mathrm{d}x$, right? Then you should use `Integrate[(1 - x)^(1/2 (-3 + d)) x^(-d/2), {x, 0, 1}]`. This gives $\Gamma \left(1-d/2\right) \Gamma \left((d-1)/2\right)/\sqrt{\pi }$ for $1< d < 2$.

Comment: No, I do not want a definite integral, I want the indefinite integral. In the context in which I am trying to solve this integral my $x$ is between $0$ and $1$, but I don't need the definite integral.

Comment: You can do a math trick: shift your $d$ by $3$ and integrate $\int x^{-(d+3)/2}(1-x)^{d/2}dx$.

Comment: You say you don't need the definite integral, but [beware](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/).

Comment: @user58955 Thanks! This is interesting, and I'm curious, why does this trick work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an [incomplete Euler beta function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Beta.html): `Beta[z0, z1, a, b]` is

$$
B_{z_0,z_1}(a,b)=\int_{z_0}^{z_1}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt.
$$

Define

```
f[d_, x_] = Beta[1, x, 1 - d/2, (d - 1)/2];
```

and check that its $x$-derivative matches your expression:

```
D[f[d, x], x] // FullSimplify
(*    (1 - x)^(1/2 (-3 + d)) x^(-d/2)    *)
```

where I've quite arbitrarily picked $z_0=1$; any value $z_0\in(0,1]$ will work (but not $z_0=0$!); even some complex values would work, as in the hypergeometric solutions coming from [user58955](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7046/user58955)'s comment.

Plot some values:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[d, x], {d, 1, 10}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An extension of [@user58955's trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285740/integrate-x-d-21-xd-3-2#comment711401_285740):

```
ans = Integrate[
    int = x^(-d/2) (1 - x)^((d - 3)/2) /. d -> d + 3, {x, 1/4, x}, 
    Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1] /. d -> d - 3 // Normal
(*
4 I^(3 - d) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (3 - d)/2, 3/2, 4] - 
 (2 I^(3 - d) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, (3 - d)/2, 3/2, 1/x])/Sqrt[x]
*)

psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[x] == int /. d -> d - 3, 
   y[1/4] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {d}]

Clear[d];
Manipulate[
 Quiet[
  Plot[{ans, psol[d][x]} /. d -> d0 // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[6], AbsoluteThickness[3]}],
  ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz],
 {d0, 4, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: As a warning to others, in 12.3 or 13.0, a [different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRpIA.png) (wrong?) result is obtained.

Comment: @Domen Just to be clear, the error comes from the `Integrate[]` result for even values of `d`. Apparently `Integrate[]` changes its behavior now and then. :)